# combine two tables in sql

Tags: sql-server-2008

By using Sql server 2008 I can return two table results like

```
College    Department   Course    Section   Passed

  X           CS         B.Sc        A        30
  X           CS         B.Sc        B        12
```

and the second result

```
College    Department   Course    Section   Failed

  X           CS         B.Sc        A        23
  X           CS         B.Sc        B        42
```

here, am joining one extra table than the first one, if I use the same query to get both the passed and failed count, the count goes wrong, thats what am using two different queries.

Am trying to combine these two tables, to get the result like

```
College    Department   Course    Section   Passed   Failed

  X           CS         B.Sc        A        30       23
  X           CS         B.Sc        B        12       42
```

but I dunno how to do this, can anyone help me out here, thanks in advance.

Note : here am joining about 3 to 5 tables in both the queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **case** Statement

```
select College,    Department ,  Course  ,  Section ,
       sum(case when <pass condition> then 1 else 0) as Passed  ,
       sum(case when <fail condition> then 1 else 0) as Failed
from <table1>
join <table2>
on (condition)
group by College,    Department ,  Course  ,  Section
```

Comment: no its not about checking pass or fail, I have to display the result as it is in my query, thats all

Comment: am joining 3 to 5 tables in both the queries,

Comment: This query will give you result as per your question.. please post what is your query. then we can understand better

Comment: sorry Joe, u were right, yours actually simplified my query, thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

```
select a.*b.failed
from ([first result query]) a
INNER JOIN ([second result query]) b on a.college=b.college and a.Department=b.Department and a.Course=b.course and a.Section=b.Section
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use inner join for your required output.

For Example,

```
Select emp.name,emp.salary,Q.qualification from employee emp inner join qualification  Q.empid=emp.empid
```

For detail refer

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp/

https://avtartime.com/sql-inner-join-with-examples/